# Hiding layer using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, layers

I am currently creating a plugin with PyQGIS. The layers all come from a PostgreSQL database. Now I would like to include a table (without geometry) for a ValueRelation without the table appearing in the layer tree.

How can I programmatically hide a layer using PyQGIS?

By default, I load the layers as follows (without the database connection code):

```
uri.setDataSource("schema", "table1", None)
lyr_table1= QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(False), "table1", 'postgres')
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(lyr_table1)
```

How do I get access to the interface of the layer tree and which method can be used for hiding?

Comment: try : `lyr_table1.setFlags(QgsMapLayer.LayerFlag(QgsMapLayer.Private))`

Comment: Unfortunately, no. ' AttributeError: type object 'QgsMapLayer' has no attribute 'Private' '

Comment: The attribute appeared in QGIS 3.4, I tested successfully under 3.18. So I guess you have a lower version than 3.4.

Comment: @J.Monticolo, thanks for your answer, I'll mark this as duplicate to keep a single question open.

Comment: QgsProject.instance (). AddMapLayer (lyr_table1, False) ... the "False" parameter was only missing to hide the layer.